# How to parse specific JSON element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

How would I parse this packet in Jquery to parse only the "**rendered**" element?

Please see the referenced image. [image] The area that is highlighted in grey is the area I want to utilize.

```
 {"content":{"rendered":"<section>\n<div class=\"container\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-6\">\n<div class=\"lc-block\">\n<div editable=\"rich\">\n<h4 id=\"the-quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-the-lazy-dog\">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog<\/h4>\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a lacus est. Etiam diam metus, lobortis non augue at, placerat viverra risus. Cras ornare faucibus laoreet. Aenean vel nisi in ipsum congue fermentum et ut arcu. Proin leo diam,<br \/>\n\t\t\t\t\t\tvulputate eu tellus ac, mattis cursus nunc. In aliquet erat ac eros congue maximus. Fusce cursus leo at elit tincidunt, consequat ultrices ante pretium. Vivamus ut dapibus nisl, nec condimentum purus.<\/p>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/p>\n<div class=\"col-md-6\">\n<div class=\"lc-block\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-12\"><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/section>\n<section>\n<div class=\"container\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-6\">\n<div class=\"lc-block\">\n<div editable=\"rich\">\n<h4 id=\"the-quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-the-lazy-dog\">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog<\/h4>\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a lacus est. Etiam diam metus, lobortis non augue at, placerat viverra risus. Cras ornare faucibus laoreet. Aenean vel nisi in ipsum congue fermentum et ut arcu. Proin leo diam,<br \/>\n\t\t\t\t\t\tvulputate eu tellus ac, mattis cursus nunc. In aliquet erat ac eros congue maximus. Fusce cursus leo at elit tincidunt, consequat ultrices ante pretium. Vivamus ut dapibus nisl, nec condimentum purus.<\/p>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/p>\n<div class=\"col-md-6\">\n<div class=\"lc-block\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-12\">\n<div class=\"lc-block bg-light\">\n<div class=\"alert alert-primary\" role=\"alert\" editable=\"rich\">1. Select the <strong>Start <\/strong>Button<\/div>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/p>\n<div class=\"lc-block\"><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/section>\n<section>\n<div class=\"container\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-12\">\n<div class=\"lc-block bg-light\">\n<div class=\"alert alert-primary\" role=\"alert\" editable=\"rich\">1. Select the <strong>Start <\/strong>Button<\/div>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/section>\n<section>\n<div class=\"container\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-12\">\n<div class=\"lc-block bg-light\">\n<div class=\"alert alert-primary\" role=\"alert\" editable=\"rich\">2. Select <strong>All&nbsp;Programs<\/strong><\/div>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/section>\n<section>\n<div class=\"container\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-12\">\n<div class=\"lc-block bg-light\">\n<div class=\"alert alert-primary\" role=\"alert\" editable=\"rich\">3. Select <strong>Microsoft Office 2016<\/strong><\/div>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/section>\n<section>\n<div class=\"container\">\n<div class=\"row\">\n<div class=\"col-md-12\">\n<div class=\"lc-block bg-light\">\n<div class=\"alert alert-primary\" role=\"alert\" editable=\"rich\">4. Select <strong>Word 2016<\/strong><\/div>\n<\/p><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/lc-block --><\/div>\n<p><!-- \/col --><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/section>\n<section><\/section>\n","protected":false},"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/pages\/149"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/pages"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/page"}],"author":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1"}],"replies":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=149"}],"version-history":[{"count":4,"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/pages\/149\/revisions"}],"predecessor-version":[{"id":188,"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/pages\/149\/revisions\/188"}],"wp:attachment":[{"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=149"}],"wp:term":[{"taxonomy":"wf_page_folders","embeddable":true,"href":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/wf_page_folders?post=149"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}}
```

I would like to output to html from this section.

Comment: Can you add the code with which you read this JSON?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you generalise your question to make it a programming question?  With the example you posted, you can just copy and paste the code once.  Are there other examples?  What is the common factor you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I don't know what your code looks like since you only provided the JSON object, but if all of this JSON is stored inside the variable `obj`, you would access it via `obj.content.rendered`. This will give you the HTML as a string.

Comment: Thank you, that was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to convert the JSON to an object, so, if the JSON string stored in `jsonString`, you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then, to access the HTML, you need to go "inside" the [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), like so:

```
let html = obj.content.rendered;
// Or, you can use brackets:
// let html = obj["content"]["rendered"];
```

Then, put the HTML inside the [jQuery constructor](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2), and [append](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/) it to the document where you want it (for example, to the body tag):

```
jQuery(html).appendTo("body");
```

And that's it!